# How to remove statusbar in iOS 7

Tags: cordova, ios7

How do I remove the status bar in iOS7 ?

I have an iOS6 fullscreen app without statusbar, that on iOS7 displays the new statusbar in translucent sytle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO in info.plist

Answer (score 1):

in your apps plist file add a row call it "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to NO